# How can I get some WebBrowser control elements by id into a string of vb.net app?

Tags: html, vb.net

I am trying to get the string value of three elements from my displayed WebBrowser control. I want to save them in my vb.net app as strings for other processing. I have tried the following code but it doesn't work. What do I need to change?

```
Dim raceName As String = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("racename").ToString
Dim raceDate As String = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("racedate").ToString
Dim boatclass As String = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("class").ToString
```

Comment: `Document.GetElementById()` returns an HtmlElement object. Calling `ToString()` on it, as for most objects, will return the object type: `{System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement}`. Maybe you want the content of the `.InnerHtml` property. If it's something else, specify what that is. Post a fragment of the HTML if you think it'll makes it easier to explain what you're after.

Comment: Problem solved, you were right, what I wanted was the .InnerHtml property. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Jimi gets the credit, he solved the problem. What I needed was the InnerHtml property.
The revised code is:

```
Dim raceName As String = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("racename").InnerHtml
Dim raceDate As String = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("racedate").InnerHtml
Dim boatclass As String = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("class").InnerHtml
```